# Status bar shows when view is on popover

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

struct ContentView: View {

@State var showPopover = false

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button(action: {
        showPopover.toggle()
      }, label: {
        Text("show popover")
      })
    }
    .padding()
    .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
      RedView()

    }
    .statusBarHidden(true)

}
```

}

struct RedView: View {
var body: some View {
Rectangle()
.fill(Color.red)
.statusBarHidden(true)

}
}

As you can see I have

```
.statusBarHidden(true)
```

on both views.

When `RedView` is shown as a popover the status bar makes itself visible.

See the clock and battery icons appear when redview is shown.

[image]

Is there a way to show a popover without the status bar showing again?